# Elevator Program has error (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c

I am new to C language and I have a problem with my code. (Sorry for my english)
I am trying to make an elevator program but When I compile it(gcc), I have a Segmentation fault error. Here is my code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

/* Elevator Program */


char elevArr[11]={0};
int pressFloor[3][11]={0}, q=0;

void PrintFloor() { // Printing floors status
    for(int i=9; i>=0; i--) {
        printf("%3d %3c\n", i+1, elevArr[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

void InputFloor() { // Place what floor's button is pressed
    int floor;
    printf("Enter (floor, Up/down): ");
    scanf("%d", &floor);
    pressFloor[0][q]=floor;
}

void UpDownFloor() { // Button for Up Down
    int ud;
    scanf("%d", ud);
    pressFloor[1][q]=ud;
}

int main() { // main module
    bool Isfirst=true; // if the program is first runned
    printf("\nElevator Program\nCreated by JSChang\nTo exit type (0, 0)\n\n");
    elevArr[0]='E';
    while(1) {
        if(Isfirst==true) {
            PrintFloor();   
            Isfirst=false;
        } else {
            q=0;
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                InputFloor();
                UpDownFloor();
                if(pressFloor[0][i]==0 && pressFloor[1][i]==0)
                        break;
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable your compiler warnings and fix all warnings:

For example:

```
int ud;
scanf("%d", ud);
```

This is wrong, the `scanf` argument has to be `&ud` not `ud`.

Answer (score 0):

try including stdbool header by writing `#include<stdbool.h>` and in the function UpDownFloor have use a "&" before ud in scanf as `scanf("%d",&ud);`